# How to ignore invalid JSON and replace invalid object with None in Python?

Tags: python, json

I want to convert a JSON tree to a Python dictionary. Here is an example of a JSON tree I might receive.

```
{"tree":{"arbitrary_text": "foo", "arbitrary_function": function helloworld() {console.log("hello world!")}}
```

As expected, when trying to decode with

```
json_obj = json.loads(raw_json)
```

a

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
```

is thrown.

The JSON is arbitrary, so the only possible way to parse the information I want is to replace the invalid JSON with something, or just not include the invalid objects in the Python tree. Is it possible to do this with the built-in JSON module(without changing it's own code). If not then is there a module that I can use?

I'm not familiar with hacking builtin modules so I am looking for a straightforward solution.]

This is what I want to achieve(Python Dictionary):

```
{'tree': {'arbitrary_text': 'foo', 'arbitrary_function': None}
```

OR

```
{'tree': {'arbitrary_text': 'foo', 'arbitrary_function': 'function helloworld() {console.log("hello world!")}'}
```

Comment: This looks like a very bad idea: since it is invalid JSON parsing can go terribly wrong and produce a totally different dictionary: the invalid parts can contain curly braces, etc.

Comment: Can you post error log here ?

Comment: I agree with the first comment. I would not accept a partially broken JSON structure, because the 'break' will most likely introduce an unexpected structure that you don't want, and you'll never know.

Comment: The problem with trying to do this is that you have at least some ability to *parse* the parts that aren't JSON, to know where they begin and end. You'd probably need a full-fledged Javascript parser for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other option as I don't have any influence on the JSON I'm receiving.

Comment: @user6769219: but this is not JSON. This looks like a JS object dump. You should use a parser that can handle this more rich language.

Comment: Could you give me an example of one?